# XSLT: Is it possible to insert HTML tags into the output of xsl's format-number function?

Tags: xslt

Given the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(//items/subitem[@name = 'name']/@value, '#,###.00')" />
```

is it even possible to wrap the resultant decimals in a superscript tag (`<sup>`)?

My research, explorations, and attempts suggest that it is not, but I'm far from an expert in using XSLT.

Any suggestions, pointers, links would be greatly appreciated.

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is indeed no. The second argument to the format-number function is a format pattern string (in XSLT 1.0), or a picture string (in XSLT 2.0, which you can read about here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#processing-picture-string)

One thing you can do though is something like this

```
<xsl:variable name="value" select="//items/subitem[@name = 'name']/@value" />
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($value), '#,###')" />
<sup>
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number($value - floor($value), '.00')" />
</sup>
```

Comment: Man, I ❤ SO. 

This is perfection. Thank you!